# Can I get container logs older than one restart ago?

Tags: kubernetes

I am writing a test to catch a case where a container fails after 5 minutes.  Once crashed, it gets restarted.  So if I wait 16 minutes, it will have crashed 3 times.

I know I can see the logs of the current container like:

```
$ kubectl logs podname containername
    service starting at 00:15
    service happy
```

And I can see the logs of the previous container like:

```
kubectl logs --previous podname containername
    service starting at 00:10
    service happy
    service sad
    service CRASHED
```

But can I get logs for containers older than one restart ago?  Something like:

```
kubectl logs --all-previous podname containername # <-- no such command
    service starting at 00:00
    service happy
    service sad
    service CRASHED
    ----
    service starting at 00:05
    service happy
    service sad
    service CRASHED
    ----
    service starting at 00:10
    service happy
    service sad
    service CRASHED
    ----
    service starting at 00:15
    service happy
```

If my test detects that it has crashed *at all* I want to capture logs that tell the whole story, not just the previous crash.

If there isn't a command that will aggregate logs for me, then can I at least find the logs one-at-a-time so that I can aggregate them myself?  If so, where would I look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container must exist in the underlying runtime to get the logs, and they are cleaned up by kubernetes.

A log aggregator like [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) is the standard way to collect logs from each container runtime to a central location. You can write the logs to a simple [file](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/file) to avoid a large ingest system and query with `jq`.